# With a rooted mobile ,Can I free up some internal storage (ROM) after delete some google apps from system

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

With a rooted mobile ,Can I free up some internal storage (ROM) after delete some google apps from system. After deleted that's apps is there any problem to other google apps like play store, google ply games and other apps in my system ? . is there any problem to my phone or system ?

Answer (score 2):

No. Deleting apps from the system does NOT free up usable space. System applications are stored in the /system partition which is not usable space to the user, you will not gain any usable space this way.

Comment: If I delete some Google apps is there any problem to other Google apps or other apps

Comment: Depends what you delete... some things like Play Services are the core to everything else, without it none (or few) of the others will work. In general, there is no need to actually delete anything, disable in the App settings or use Titanium Backup to "freeze" the apps. Deleting them is not reversible.